# How to find mapping between page slots and CMS JSON in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm new to Hybris and is kicking off a project in Spartacus, and have setup a sample B2C storefront. According to the Spartacus documentation, CMS JSON maps to components in Spartacus, I was wondering how do I find the mapping of the content slots on the DOM with the JSON.

[image]

[image]

For exampple, in the home page of the sample site the PreHeader, Site Logo, etc slots are populated on the DOM, how do I map these from the CMS JSON? Or am I looking at the wrong sources?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following pages in the Spartacus documentation, they should help:

- https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/page-layout/
- https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/creating-pages-and-components/
- https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/